# take count of item depend on the specific calulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

i have a query like this:

```
SELECT T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode,
       T_Master_Item.itemName AS Description,
       T_Master_Item.categoryCode AS Category,
       sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) AS Qty
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail
LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Master_Item ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T_Master_Item.itemCode
GROUP BY T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode,
         T_Master_Item.itemName,
         T_Master_Item.categoryCode
HAVING sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0
ORDER BY T_Master_Item.categoryCode,
         T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode
```

in the query i am getting out put like this:

```
itemcode   description   category     qty
076-00002  bottom                       2
```

**in the same query i want to add two more column 1 is goodcount 2 is defectivecount** ..
in the doctype column we have good and defective item.so i want to add count of that.

```
my expected out put like this:
 itemcode   description   category     qty  good   defective
  076-00002  bottom                    2       1      1
```

how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` in the expression passed to `sum`. So you can for example do something like this:

```
sum(case when DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: can u able to re write full query please

Comment: @jasbacker Just add it as another column, no big deal. It should work fine as part of your query. And of course, add another for the `DEFECT` case.

Comment: sir i tryed ..but i am not getting proper answer.. i want to calculate good and defective count of that particular 2 qty only.no need to calculate all

Comment: i hop u understood my qustion

Comment: @jasbacker You're grouping by three columns. That's the same columns used in the `sum`. If that's not what you want to group by, change the `group by` clause. If you want ot add multiple conditions to the `sum`, that's fine too - say, something like `when DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' and qty > 0`. Though in your case, you should IMO just add `qty > 0` to the `where` clause - you only want to group over the items that have a quantity over zero if I understand you correctly.

Comment: while i add code sum(case when DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' then 1 else 0 end and Qty >0) am getting error..that s why

Comment: @jasbacker You need to add the extra clause to the *condition*, not to the result of the `case`. Something like `1 and Qty > 0` makes no sense, obviously.

Comment: @jasbacker How much experience with SQL do you really have? Do you have any idea what the query you have is doing and what it's *supposed to* be doing?

Comment: sir Please,,can u show me how to add extra clause? Please ,,i am struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

I Updated ans but I was not able to test it due to not having test data, can you please try this

```
 Select T.itemCode,T.Description,T.Category,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Good,
 SUM(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Defective  
 from 
 (SELECT T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName as Description,
       T_Master_Item.categoryCode as Category, 
 SUM(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) As Qty,
 FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T_Master_Item ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T_Master_Item.itemCode
 GROUP BY T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode, T_Master_Item.itemName,T_Master_Item.categoryCode
 HAVING SUM(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0 
 ORDER BY T_Master_Item.categoryCode, T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode
 ) T
 inner join T_BOE_Stock_Detail ON T_BOE_Stock_Detail.itemCode = T.itemCode
 GROUP BY T.itemCode, T.Description,T.Category
```

Comment: SUM of 3 * NULL would return NULL instead of 0

Comment: sir this is query ok..but i want to calculate good and defective count of that particular 2 qty

Comment: @jasbacker can you please elaborate more? what do you mean by `count of that particular 2 qty`?

Comment: sir..u sow that am taking qty field after subtracting..i want good and defective count ,only for that particular value

Comment: in my table u can see that ID: 18625 and 16998..only i want to calculate that row only. becouse in my query one condition is there sum(T_BOE_Stock_Detail.qty - T_BOE_Stock_Detail.ReservedQty) > 0

Comment: sir you understand my question

Comment: Yup, give me few mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84993/discussion-between-tirthak-shah-and-jas-backer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t_boe_stock_detail.itemcode, t_master_item.itemname as description,
t_master_item.categorycode as category, 
sum(t_boe_stock_detail.qty - t_boe_stock_detail.reservedqty) as qty,
sum(case when doctype = 'good' then 1 end) as good,
sum(case when doctype = 'defective' then 1 end) as defective 
from t_boe_stock_detail 
left outer join t_master_item on t_boe_stock_detail.itemcode = t_master_item.itemcode
group by t_boe_stock_detail.itemcode, t_master_item.itemname,t_master_item.categorycode
having sum(t_boe_stock_detail.qty - t_boe_stock_detail.reservedqty) > 0 
order by t_master_item.categorycode, t_boe_stock_detail.itemcode
```

Comment: sir this is query ok..but i want to calculate good and defective count of that particular 2 qty

Comment: dear sir..did u see my expected out put

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full script, the performance has been improved a bit by aggregating before calculating:

```
SELECT BOE.itemCode,
       M.itemName AS Description,
       M.categoryCode AS Category,
       sum(BOE.qty) - sum(BOE.ReservedQty) AS Qty,
       count(case when DOCTYPE = 'GOOD' then 1 end) good,
       count(case when DOCTYPE = 'DEFECTIVE' then 1 end) defective
FROM T_BOE_Stock_Detail BOE
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  T_Master_Item M
ON BOE.itemCode = M.itemCode
GROUP BY BOE.itemCode,
         M.itemName,
         M.categoryCode
HAVING sum(BOE.qty) > sum(BOE.ReservedQty)
ORDER BY M.categoryCode,
         BOE.itemCode
```

Not sure how to prefix DOCTYPE, you should use M or BOE in my example

Comment: sir this is query ok..but i want to calculate good and defective count of that particular 2 qty